# Why postgres container changes folder`s owner (docker-compose)

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

My docker-compose.yml is

```
  database:
    container_name: k4fntr_database
    build: ./docker/postgres
    restart: always
    environment:
      ENV: ${APP_ENV}
      TESTING_DB: ${DB_DATABASE_TESTING}
      POSTGRES_DB: ${DB_DATABASE}
      POSTGRES_USER: ${DB_USERNAME}
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
    ports:
      - "15432:5432"
    volumes:
    - ./docker/postgres/pg-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    networks:
      - backend-network
```

and my Dockerfile is

```
FROM postgres:10.5-alpine

COPY /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/ /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/

RUN chmod 0755 -R /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
```

I have a problem when I run

> docker-compose up -d --build

a folder which is called pg-data is created with wrong permissions from user "70" and group "root"

[image]

This permissions don't let me to do any things such as look inside the folder. In addition, when I try to rebuild the container with

> docker-compose up -d --build

I get an error

> PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied:
> '/home/ubuntu/PhpstormProjects/fntr/docker/postgres/pg-data' [5262]
> Failed to execute script docker-compose

I run docker-compose as user ubuntu:ubuntu.

The situation was changed a little bit when I created folder BEFORE run

> docker-compose up -d --build

In this case the folder has group "ubuntu" but the owner is still "70"

[image]

but there is no some effects and all problems are exists

Comment: Please add Dockerfile for the image. Most likely, the container is running as user 70 and is creating a folder using this. Inside the container, user 70 is resolvable through `/etc/passwd` but it is not resolvable on the host machine.

Comment: I have dockerfile but there aren`t some interesting things

FROM postgres:10.5-alpine
COPY /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/ /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/

Answer (score 1):

Postgres run an entrypoint file when a container is started.

https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/blob/master/10/docker-entrypoint.sh#L36

This is the function that changes the permission of the directory inside docker container. Since this directory is mounted on the host file-system too, the permissions are reflected there.

On your system, check the user currently mapped to uid-999. You can have a clue from there. Avoid posting /etc/passwd or /etc/shadow file here

You need to pass User in docker-compose

See https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres  -> Arbitrary --user Notes

Comment: cat /etc/passwd | grep 999
guest-sdklnd:x:999:999:Guest:/tmp/guest-sdklnd:/bin/bash

Comment: I can't understand. Postgres doing that inside the container, but I have problem with my filesystem